# Passing an array into a function, nothing outputting

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I am trying to create something that fills in an array with 100 random numbers between 1 and 100. This was working fine when it was in the main function, but when I put it in an int function nothing outputs; I must be missing something simple as I'm just beginning. What can I do to fix this?

```
 #include "stdafx.h"
    #include <time.h>
    #include <math.h>
    #include <iostream>

int arrayer(int ar[101],  int i);

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    int ar[101];

    for (int i = 1; i < 101; ++i)
    {
        int arrayer(int ar[101], int i);
    }
    return 0;
}



int arrayer(int ar[101],  int i) {


    ar[i] = rand() % 100 + 1;

    if (ar[i] < 10) {
        std::cout << i << ": " << "0" << ar[i] << std::endl;
    }

    else {
        std::cout << i << ": " << ar[i] << std::endl;
    }

    return ar[i];

}
```

Comment: you're missing a call to your function `arrayer`

Comment: you are not calling your function, you just have another declaration inside your loop. Try `arrayer(ar,i);` instead.

Comment: If an answer has helped you please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling and declaring the function incorrectly. This is what it should look like:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>

int arrayer(int ar[101],  int i);

int main() {
    srand(time(0));
    int ar[101];

    for (int i = 1; i < 101; ++i)
    {
        arrayer(ar, i);
    }
    return 0;
}

int arrayer(int* ar,  int i) {
    ar[i] = rand() % 100 + 1;

    if (ar[i] < 10) {
        std::cout << i << ": " << "0" << ar[i] << std::endl;
    }

    else {
        std::cout << i << ": " << ar[i] << std::endl;
    }

    return ar[i];
}
```

Notice also that you're not using the return value, so you can omit that if it's not going to ever be used.

EDIT: You can actually replace the if-else for printing the value with this:

```
std::cout << i << ": " << setw(2) << setfill('0') << ar[i] << std::endl;
```

You will need to include <iomanip> to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the arguments in a very wrong manner, the way of calling a function is way more different than declaring or defining it. You need to call the function as :

```
arrayer(ar, i);
```

Just pass the address of the array, `ar` as it is and the variable `i`.

Also, its better to have the function `arrayer` return `void` rather than `int`, since the array gets modified when passed to the function and the value gets printed in the function itself, so you don't need to return anything.

Answer (score 0):

Well there is nothing in output because you never *call* the `arrayer` function!

In your loop, you just *declare* again the function. As the new declaration is compatible with the previous one, the compiler accepts it without error.

In order to actually call the function, you need an function *call* expression:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 101; ++i)
{
    arrayer(ar, i);
}
```